# Creating GraphQL mutation

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, github-graphql

I have the following sample mutation:

```
mutation {
  checkoutCreate(input: {
    lineItems: [{ variantId: "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80", quantity: 1 }]
  }) {
    checkout {
       id
       webUrl
       lineItems(first: 5) {
         edges {
           node {
             title
             quantity
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using .net [GraphQL client](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client). I would like to somehow pass lineItems list to this query. I did the following:

```
mutation {
  checkoutCreate(input: {
    $lineItems
  }) {
    checkout {
       id
       webUrl
       lineItems(first: 5) {
         edges {
           node {
             title
             quantity
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

C# code:

```
    dynamic lineItems = new List<dynamic>
    {
        new
        {
            variantId = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80",
            quantity = 2
        }
    };

    var request = new GraphQLRequest
    {
        Query = m_resource.Resource.GetString("CheckoutCreate"), // Gets from resource file the above string
        Variables = lineItems 
    };

    var response = await m_client.PostAsync(request);
```

I keep getting:

> GraphQLHttpException: Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code:
>   BadRequest

Is there a way to do this? or do I have to replace within a string?

**EDIT:**

I've tried this (and 20 other ways and still getting errors). All i'm trying to do is pass in a list of LineItems.

```
mutation CreateCheckout($input: LineItemsInput!) {
  checkoutCreate(input: $input) {
    checkout {
       id
       webUrl
       lineItems(first: 5) {
         edges {
           node {
             title
             quantity
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}

        var request = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = m_resource.Resource.GetString("CheckoutCreate"),
            Variables = new
            {
                LineItemsInput = new List<dynamic>
                    {
                        new
                        {
                            variantId = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80",
                            quantity = 2
                        }
                    }
            }
        };
```

Json request looks like this:

```
{
  "Query": "mutation CreateCheckout($input: LineItemsInput!) {\r\n  checkoutCreate(input: $input) {\r\n    checkout {\r\n       id\r\n       webUrl\r\n       lineItems(first: 5) {\r\n         edges {\r\n           node {\r\n             title\r\n             quantity\r\n           }\r\n         }\r\n       }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}",
  "OperationName": null,
  "Variables": {
    "LineItemsInput": [
      {
        "variantId": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80",
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @galkin and @David Maze, I solved it like this:

```
mutation checkoutCreate($input: CheckoutCreateInput!) {
  checkoutCreate(input: $input) {
    checkout {
      id
    }
    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

c# code:

```
            var request = new GraphQLRequest
            {
                Query = m_resource.Resource.GetString("CheckoutCreate"),
                Variables = new
                {
                    input = new
                    {
                        LineItems = lineItems // List<LineItem>
                    }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables is an object, a single value.

With pseudocode, you have `variables = lineItems`, but you need `variables = { lineItems: lineItems }`

Answer (score 1):

In the query itself, you need to [declare the variable and its type](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables).  In your case this might look like

```graphql
mutation CreateCheckout($lineItems: [LineItem!]!) {
  checkoutCreate(input: {
    $lineItems
  }) { ... FieldsFromTheQuestion }
```

The name of the operation (`CreateCheckout`) can be anything that's meaningful to you; it's not specified in the schema.

@galkin's answer is probably relevant too: when you make the request you need to pass the line item list under the key `"input"`, matching the variable name in the query.  The [raw JSON request](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) should look something like

```
{
  "query": "mutation CreateCheckout ...",
  "variables": {
    "input": [
      {
        "variantId": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC80",
        "quantity" 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```